# PHP money_format: issues with values 0.00/0.50/.50

Tags: php

I am currently validating US Currency along with a decimal number format. I am using the function `money_format`but the issues is that certain values is returning an error.

How can i have the function work when the input value is `0.00` or `0.50`? [Example](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/dropdown-menu/test1.php)

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST['price'])){
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $priceString = empty($price['price'])?null:trim($price['price']);
        if(!empty($priceString)) { 
            $price = str_replace("$", "", $price); 
                if  (preg_match('/^[+\-]?\d+(\.\d+)?$/', $price)){
                 echo ('<div id="price"><span id="resultval"><h2>Price:</h2>'.money_format('%n', $price).'</span></div>');
                           }
                     else {
             echo ('<div id="price"><span id="resultval"><h2>Price:</h2><div class="errorMessage">Enter a valid number in US currency format.</div></span></div>'); 
                           }
}
            else {
            echo '';
            }
}
```

Comment: use - money_format() or number_format(); don't use a regular expression for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is here:

```
$price = $_POST['price'];
$priceString = empty($price['price'])?null:trim($price['price']);
```

Note that that `$price` is a String; so, `$price['price']` returns the first character of that array because the interpreter should logically attempt `$price[intval('price')]` where  `intval('price') == 0`.  Consequently, `$price['price'] == $price[0]`.

For example, if the input was `0.00`, then `$price['price']` would return `0` which is considered empty according to the PHP manual.

I think you intend for the following (which works with `0.00` and `0.50`):

```
$price = $_POST['price'];
$priceString = empty($price)?null:trim($price);
```

Comment: oh wow, I totally skipped over that error. thank you! it works fine now